# how to grep and grab docker image_id from 'docker images' cmd via cli without selecting with mouse?

Tags: docker, grep, dockerfile

```
[banner@stapp03 ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              26828d185a8f        5 seconds ago       125MB
ubuntu              latest              174c8c134b2a        3 weeks ago         77.8MB
```

there are 2 images - i want to type command in cli and grab latest image id (first row) and use it for other subsequent commands.
Not use mouse click to select image id, how to do this?

Comment: What code is going to use this image ID?  Can you use a language-native Docker SDK to list the images and find the ones you need, rather than trying to interpret the human-readable output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print image id of the first image then you may use:

```bash
docker images | awk 'NR == 2 {print $3}'
```

Here:

- `NR == 2`: Selects 2nd row
- `{print $3}`: Prints 3rd field i.e. **Image Id**

Answer (score 0):

We can define the format of the output for every `docker` command through `--format <fmt-string>`. Details are explained on the [corresponding `docs.docker.com` page](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/).

If we want the ids of all images, we can run

```
$ docker image ls --format {{.Id}}
```

If we want the ids of, for example, only the ubuntu image(s), we can run

```
$ docker image ls ubuntu --format {{.Id}}
```

If we want to store the output of the command in a bash array, we can use

```
$ mapfile -t foo < <(docker image ls --format {{.Id}})
```

For example, a subsequent

```
$ echo "${#foo[@]}"
```

will show us the size of the array.